# How to get first videoId , title , description and thumbnails high value from this json format?

Tags: php, json

How to get first videoId , title , description and thumbnails high value from this json format ?

I use this this code

```
<?PHP
$curl_value = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=3&search_query=test&key=youtube_api_key');
curl_setopt($curl_value, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json_exec = curl_exec($curl_value);
$result_json = json_decode($json_exec);
$video_id = $result_json->items[0]->videoId;
$title = $result_json->items[0]->snippet->title;
$description = $result_json->items[0]->snippet->description;
$thumbnails = $result_json->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->high;

echo $video_id;
echo $title;
echo $description;
echo $thumbnails;
?>
```

.

But not get any data , how can i do ?

For this case i want to get

videoId = `iKzRIweSBLA`

title = `Ed Sheeran - Perfect [Official Lyric Video]`

description = `Out Now: https://atlanti.cr/yt-album Subscribe to Ed's channel: http://test.ly/SubscribeToEdSheeran Follow Ed on... Facebook: ...`

thumbnails = `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKzRIweSBLA/hqdefault.jpg`

This is json result

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/fkLih7vu8hjlSWPap-46qmMBkKw\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAMQAA",
 "regionCode": "TH",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 3
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/xzdNtvTMaihnGappsfbZRCdysc4\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "iKzRIweSBLA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-09-22T07:02:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC0C-w0YjGpqDXGB8IHb662A",
    "title": "Ed Sheeran - Perfect [Official Lyric Video]",
    "description": "Out Now: https://atlanti.cr/yt-album Subscribe to Ed's channel: http://test.ly/SubscribeToEdSheeran Follow Ed on... Facebook: ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKzRIweSBLA/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKzRIweSBLA/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKzRIweSBLA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Ed Sheeran",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/7lxJIhHg_j7RWlEuZp87hFExzCg\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "nfs8NYg7yQM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-24T17:00:05.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCwppdrjsBPAZg5_cUwQjfMQ",
    "title": "Charlie Puth - Attention [Official Video]",
    "description": "Download and Stream \"Attention\": https://Atlantic.lnk.to/AttentionID Pre-Order Voicenotes: https://Atlantic.lnk.to/VoicenotesID Exclusive VoiceNotes Merchandise ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nfs8NYg7yQM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nfs8NYg7yQM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nfs8NYg7yQM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Charlie Puth",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/HOZpkTZCsq-gixbvF4mQGcdiepE\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "kXYiU_JCYtU"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2007-03-05T08:12:00.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCZU9T1ceaOgwfLRq7OKFU4Q",
    "title": "Numb (Official Video) - Linkin Park",
    "description": "Linkin Park \"Numb\" off of the album METEORA. Directed by Joe Hahn. http://www.linkinpark.com | http://LPUnderground.com iTunes: http://go.lprk.co/ml/3pb/ ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kXYiU_JCYtU/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kXYiU_JCYtU/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kXYiU_JCYtU/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Linkin Park",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `title` and `description` already work; `video_id` and `thumbnails` are very close.

```
$video_id    = $result_json->items[0]->id->videoId;
$title       = $result_json->items[0]->snippet->title;
$description = $result_json->items[0]->snippet->description;
$thumbnails  = $result_json->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->high->url;
```